# Get Image Data on Click Canvas with Exact coordinates

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas, getimagedata

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3nDP3/6/)

I am trying to click a canvas (having linear gradient) and getting image data at the point of click

Also I want to place a relative positioned yellow(picker) at that (click) point

Problem1 : When i click at lower part (white) it gives me wrong value of colour

Problem2: yellow(picker) is not placed exactly at click point

Note :Canvas looks round because of border-radius:50%

Important part of code given at (above fiddle link) is

```
$(wheel_canvas).click(function(e)
{
    dragging = false;
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;

    can_p = $('#wheel_canvas').offset();
    x = x - $(document).scrollLeft() - can_p.left;
    x = y - $(document).scrollTop() - can_p.top;

    $('#wheel_picker').css({'left':x+'px','top':y+'px'});
    var data=wheel_context.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
    pixelData = data;
    rgbString = 'rgb('+pixelData[0]+', '+pixelData[1]+', '+pixelData[2]+')';
    hex = rgb2hex(rgbString);

    $('#color').val(hex);
    $('#color').css('background',hex);

    $('#feedback').html("Coordinates : "+x+","+y+"  Color: "+hex);
});
```

**Edit**
Answer including fiddle would be better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your canvas has a border radius. With a border radius, for some reason, the mouse coordinates get messed up. Instead, I used a square canvas, but used the `arc()` method to draw a circle.

```
wheel_context.fillStyle = wheel_grd;
wheel_context.beginPath();
wheel_context.arc(centerX, centerY, LARGE_RADIUS, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
wheel_context.fill();
```

Then, I removed the smaller silver canvas. The problem with that was it was supposed to stop mouse events from bubbling up (i.e. if you clicked on the silver part, it wouldn't register as a color) - however, it was also stopping the mouse events close to it (because, even with a border radius, it was actually a square according to the browser). Instead, I used the same circle method (`arc`) to draw a smaller silver circle.

```
wheel_context.fillStyle = "silver";
wheel_context.beginPath();
wheel_context.arc(centerX, centerY, SMALL_RADIUS, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
wheel_context.fill();
```

(Right now, `LARGE_RADIUS` is 150 and `SMALL_RADIUS` is 110. You can adjust these if you would like). To check if the mouse was in the silver part or the colored part, I calculated the distance from the center. If it was smaller than the radius of the silver circle, you know it was in the silver circle.

```
if (Math.sqrt(
            (x - centerX) * (x - centerX) + // Square of x difference
            (y - centerY) * (y - centerY)  // Square of y difference
            ) < SMALL_RADIUS) return;
```

I also fixed a few typos that were preventing the mouse location from being registered accurately.

The finished product is http://jsfiddle.net/kNTVZ/

Note: A lot of your variables weren't properly defined. You need a `var` to keep them from being global.

Comment: Sooperb Excellent effort resulting in excellent answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`pageX` and `pageY` are sometimes unreliable cross-browser.

Since you're using jQuery already, try using it to normalize your event:

```
$(wheel_canvas).click(function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    e = jQuery.event.fix(e);    

    dragging = false;    
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;

    // ... rest of code
}
```